# data-title not getting updated on button tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I have a button whose tooltip gets updated on enable/disable. But its not.Here is the binding js and html. When I use init then it doesn't but when I use update it does but then clickHandlers gets called multiple times. I am using knockout and bootstrap.

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"
            id="displaySubmitBtn" data-bind="formSave: {text: isFormComplete() ? '' : missingRequiredTooltip, enable: isFormComplete, click: submitEstimateFromDisplay},
            text: bundle.submit_button_label, visible: isSubmitVisible"
            data-placement="bottom" data-backdrop="true">
    </button>


 ko.bindingHandlers.formSave = {

        init: function (el, valueAccessor) {
            var $el = $(el),
                saveEnabled = valueAccessor()['enable'],
                text = _.isFunction(valueAccessor()['text']) ? valueAccessor()['text']() : valueAccessor()['text'],
                placement = _.isString(valueAccessor()['placement']) ? valueAccessor()['placement'] : 'bottom',
                container = _.isString(valueAccessor()['container']) ? valueAccessor()['container'] : 'body',
                clickHandler = valueAccessor()['click'];

            var enabler = function (enabled) {
                //  not using $el.prop('disabled') on purpose so BS tooltip will show
                if (enabled) {
                    // enable the button
                    $el.removeClass('disabled');
                    $el.attr('data-title', undefined).tooltip('destroy');
                 }
                else {
                    $el.addClass('disabled');
                }

                $el.attr('data-title', text);

                $el.tooltip({
                    //title: text,
                    placement: placement,
                    container: container
                });

            };

            // call enabler to disable/ enable button and assign tooltip
            enabler(saveEnabled());
            // enabler listens to the computed method on button getting enabled/diabled
            saveEnabled.subscribe(enabler);

            $el.on("click", function (evt) {
                if (!$el.is('.disabled')) {
                    $el.attr('data-title', undefined).tooltip('destroy');
                    if(clickHandler) {
                        clickHandler(evt);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    evt.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

Comment: you should set the "title" attribute and not "data-title"

Comment: Title did not work so I used data-title

Answer (score 1):

You should be setting the `title` attribute, not `data-title`